# I need the expression to get the current date which should work in DB2 and SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, db2-400

I need the expression to get the current date which should work in DB2 and SQL Server 2014

I want a query to runs on both SQL Server 2014 and DB2 and returns the current date.

Is it possible?

I tried `CURRENT_DATE`, it does not work in SQL Server.

`GetDate()` does not work in DB2.

Please help.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
 I've posted this link because I noticed you haven't accepted any answers yet.

Comment: You will find your future questions will receive better responses if you accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is an ANSI SQL function whereas `GETDATE` is the TSQL version of the same function.

Comment: You're right. That returns something. Not sure about timezone though

Comment: Question doesn't mention timezone. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does not have a timezone portion. I'd assume it is the local server time

Comment: That's why I still upvoted. Just mentioning the difference - they don't always produce same result

Comment: Thanks Guys , I used CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and I really do not care about the timezone as of now , so it worked .

Comment: The usual course of action at this point would be to accept an answer.

Comment: thx for the lame revenge downvote on a clearly correct answer.